# Get Error while running UIAUTOMATORVIEW in MAC M1 ( Monterey )

Tags: java, bash

Does anyone have a similar issue with me, currently I'm trying to do testing apps using android  Android Studio, but I got an error like this after executing UIAutomatorviewer?

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableTreeItem
```

Below is my configuration on Bash_Profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/husinhabsyi/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/x86_64
```